# Configuration files when running java program in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I have simple java application that uses `log4j.properties` file for logger configuration. I keep this file in `bin` folder and logger reads it fine. But it is not very convenient since `Eclipse` for some mystic reason not shows `bin` folder in `project explorer`. What is logic in total of placing configuration files in eclipse java project? Is bin folder only one right place?

Comment: You can put in any place or any folder but the context should be available to your eclipse IDE that is to build path

Comment: we have our log4j.properties in the project folder( just next to where src folder is)

Answer (score 1):

You should never keep your file in the `bin` folder. The `bin` folder is transient in nature - if someone does a `clean..` on the project it will be removed. Keep the file in `src` folder (or any source folder). When the project is built in will be automatically copied to `bin` folder.

You can see all folders using the eclipse's `Navigator` view - besides changing the view options for the Project Explorer view.

Comment: I have placed *.properties and *.ini file to srs directory. After build only *.properties is copied to bin folder. How to ask Eclipse copy also ini file?

Comment: If you do not change any settings - it should copy *all non-java* files from `src` to `bin`. Check under your build-path/source tab, whether any files are excluded. Just do a clean build and check again.

Comment: clean+build solved problem. But got another one. I have jar library placed in /lib/ that uses properties file placed in project root directory. When I move properties file to /src  and buil+run I found that library not founds its properties automatically copied to /bin. When props is in root - runs fine

Comment: Project root is the working directory (by default) for running the program. You can leave those files in the root itself. My answer pertains to only the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when working with Eclipse (or other build tools) you try not to touch your `bin` folder. If you throw it away building your project again should fully reconstruct the `bin` folder.

Eclipse achieves this by automatically copying files from your source folder(s) to your bin folder. You can place your `log4j.properties` in the `src` folder (and refresh the folder in eclipse by selecting it and pressing F5). Then you can see in your systems filebrowser that it has been automatically placed in the `bin` folder. Any changes you make from eclipse are automatically copied to the bin folder, changes outside of eclipse require a refresh. Note that if you have turned of the option 'Build automatically', you will need to build for this to happen.

Alternatively you can create a new 'source folder', and use it only for configuration files. To do this, make a normal folder in your project and right click it in the package explorer. Select 'Build Path' -> 'Use as source folder'

Comment: "Any changes you make from eclipse are automatically copied to the bin folder"... as long as you use the "build automatically" option.

Comment: @LittleSanti Good point, added it the answer. Note that this is on by default.

Answer (score 0):

To see bin folder:

```
 Customize View -> Filters
```

[image]

Uncheck **Java Output Folders**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, properties files (as well as any other resource file) must be located *at source code directories*:

- On a general Java project, in the `src` folder (or subfolder).
- On a Maven project, in the `src/main/resources`, `src/test/resources` folder (or subfolder).

In this way, Eclipse will copy the all resources files to the output folder (`bin` on a general Java project) when building the project.

**It is not recommended to manage files in the output folder manually**, precisely because Eclipse overrides them in every build.

The contents of the output folder are hidden for a practical reason: Those contents are generated by Eclipse and not by the programmer; the programmer should not care about them. This is so in the *project view* and the *packages view*. But you can always see all the folders in the *navigator view*.